# Find the closest server in the network

Tags: java, traceroute

Given a list of servers & a list of clients, how to find a server that is closest to a particular host using "traceroute"? The program should be in java.

Comment: Apparently, he wants someone to tell him HOW to do it - and I don't see what's wrong with the question "is there a way to get tracerout-like functionality in Java".

Comment: Sorry I never said there was anything wrong with the question in fact I re-tagged it to Java. So more relevant people would look at it.

Answer (score 2):

What do you define as "closest"? Lots of hops in a traceroute do not indicate closeness just devices the packet routes through. Ping is also not too great as it just shows latency.
What I would suggest is if you are on the web use [BGP](http://www.ssfnet.org/bgp/) to work out closeness. If you are on a lan or you get a tie with BGP then fall back to [Traceroute](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/act365/net/ping/Traceroute.html).

Those links go to Java implementations of BGP and traceroute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done using only the standard Java API, since it does not support the ICMP protocol sufficiently. You may be able to do it using [Jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/).